# Angular will not match directive as invoked as tag

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I defined a custom Angular directive:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('lsLedger', function() {
  return {
    // restrict: 'E', // FIXME - directive will only match on attribute, not tag.
    controller: LedgerCtrl,
    templateUrl: '/template/ledger',
/*    compile: function(el, attributes) {
      console.log('ledger:compile');
      console.log(el);
    },
*/
  };
});
```

I was surprised to find that Angular will only match it if it is invoked like so:
`<div ls-ledger />`
not `<ls-ledger />`

Am I missing something here?

Comment: You need `restrict:'E'`  (commented out code) to use element restriction on the directive if you are below 1.3

Comment: I thought I had done that before but it didn't work.  Now it works!  Thanks.  You might want to re-post your comment as an answer because it definitely qualifies as one.  If you do, I'll check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the version of angular below 1.3 because if you are on 1.3 directive's restricted to attribute and elements only by default. But if you are version 1.2 of angular then the default restriction is applied only at attribute level. So you would need to add `restict : 'E'` and `restrict:'EA'` in your directive settings.

From 1.3 documentation:-

> When you create a directive, it is restricted to attribute and elements only by default. In order to create directives that are triggered by class name, you need to use the restrict option.

From 1.2 documentation:-

> When you create a directive, it is restricted to attribute only by default. In order to create directives that are triggered by element or class name, you need to use the restrict option.

Comment: My bad.  I am using 1.2 but was reading the docs for 1.3.  N00b!  Thanks for your help, PSL.